# Find the ratio of the lengths of the bisectors of internal angles of $B$ and $C$

Tags: geometry

The ratios of the lengths of the sides $BC$ and $AC$ of a triangle $ABC$ to the radius of the circumscribed circle are equal to $2$ and $\frac{3}{2}$ respectively.Find the ratio of the lengths of the bisectors of internal angles of $B$ and $C$.

---

We are given $\frac{BC}{R}=\frac{a}{R}=2$ and $\frac{AC}{R}=\frac{b}{R}=\frac{3}{2}$,where $R$ is the circumradius of the triangle $ABC$.
$a=2R,b=\frac{3}{2}R$
I know that $m_b$=length of angle bisector of angle $B=\frac{2\sqrt{acs(s-b)}}{a+c}$ and  $m_c$=length of angle bisector of angle $C=\frac{2\sqrt{abs(s-c)}}{a+b}$ but i need the third side in order to use these formulae,which i do not know.What should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) prove that $A = \frac{\pi}{2}$:
Using consequence of $\sin$-theorem :
$$b = 2R\sin{A}$$
Now you could finish by yourself.

Comment: There is a minor typo in your post,$a=2R\sin A$,but i understood the crux of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use known formula of the bisector length

$$ m_c= \frac{2 a b \cos (A/2)}{a+b}  $$

and triangle half angle  identity

$$ \cos (C/2) =\sqrt{ \frac{s(s-c)}{ab} } $$

to get bisector length in your formula. You can use the Sine Rule and cycle the sides with symmetry.